# Not pre-populating lookup field when creating new legal contract from account page

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking, custom-url

The following URL custom button is supposed to use a specific record type, which it does, and prepopulate the account lookup field. It is not populating the field whenever I create new record though.

I dont get any errors though.

Tried this (using master lookup field):

```
https://ORG.lightning.force.com/a1G/e?&CF00Nn0000000rM5s={!Account.Id}
```

Tried this (using master lookup field):

```
/a1G/e?CF00Nn0000000rM5s={!Legal_Contract__c.Account_LC__c}&CF00Nn0000000rM5s_lkid={!Account.Id}
```

Tried this (using lookup field):

```
/a1G/e?CF00Nn0000000u87h={!Account.Name}&CF00Nn0000000u87h_lkid={!Account.Id}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct method to use URL hacks in Salesforce Lightning. You can achieve the functionality using flows and quick actions.